# What exactly "All remaining projects" in views mean?

Tags: sonarqube

In Sonarqube -->**Views** --> Create/Edit existing Views --> Project selection mode --> ***All remaining Projects***

What exactly is the meaning of "All remaining projects" ?

Comment: Please contact Support for commercial products.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you let me know how to contact Sonar support, or Sonar Source support?

Answer (score 0):

Please contact SonarSource for commercial products => https://www.sonarsource.com/forms/contact-us.html